# In Firefox OAuth window opens in new tab instead of popup..?

Tags: authorization, google-drive-api

I'm getting authorization through JavaScript API the usual way (I think):

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: client_id, 
    scope: scope,
    immediate: false
}, callback);
```

which opens authorization interface as expected, but while in Chrome it shows up in popup, Firefox opens it in a new tab (at least on Mac). This is obviously undesired and unexpected behavior. Is there a known way to workaround this? We would like to have it in a popup.

I remember I had the same problem with Firefox popups in different app, and I was able to overcome it by passing `dialog=1` to `window.open` as additional param. I checked the `gapi` source and it obviously lacks this parameter. Is it done on purpose? I do not see any way in API how we could inject additional param in there.

Comment: If you can share your FF user-agent, I may try to reproduce it.

Comment: Here: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0

Answer (score 1):

Normally, on Firefox, the dialog opens up in a popup similar to the behavior you experience on other browsers. For mobile browsers, the fallback is opening in another window since it's more appropriate to the user. I would not suggest you to force pass a parameter.

Comment: It's quite easy to check for mobile environment I think, or target Firefox only. Does it open in a popup for you?

Comment: @jayarjo, yes, it opens a popup for me.

Comment: Maybe you have it explicitly defined in settings or something? I know there is a switch, it's just that by default it opens in new tab for me, unless someone played with my workstation in my absence... hm... need to check that as well.